# Map/reduce on MongoDB grouping by an external key

Tags: mongodb, relational-database, nosql

I am in the process of choosing a database for a project and new to the NoSQL world. I am not sure if one of the query we will run could be done using NoSQL. I think that my mind is just not able to do the query, yet. :)

I am very interested in map/reduce that's why I try to push in using a NoSQL database.

I have two collections. One for devices, one for messages.

```
[{
  deviceId: 1,
  uuid: "30be317c-e586-4448-8fed-1a9481710670"
}, {
  deviceId: 1,
  uuid: "9878917c-e586-4448-8fed-1a9481710670"
}, {
  deviceId: 3,
  uuid: "as2e317c-e586-9878-8fed-1a9481710670"
}]

[{
  uuid: "30be317c-e586-4448-8fed-1a9481710670",
  message: "Hello world",
}, {
  uuid: "9878917c-e586-4448-8fed-1a9481710670",
  message: "Bonjour monde",
}, {
  uuid: "as2e317c-e586-9878-8fed-1a9481710670",
  message: "Hola Mundo",
}]
```

Now I want to run a map/reduce command, and grouping the messages by their `deviceId`. In the example, "Hello World" and "Bonjour Monde" should be grouped using the same key. I cannot think of a way to group them in the map() method.

Note that the data is now stored in files so I don't limit my research in MongoDB. It is just the first one I picked since pretty much everything in the application uses JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in theory this is doable by doing some kind of joining within the map function.
You can use the "db" object and all related queries that you would do in the shell.

```
db.runCommand({mapReduce: "test", map: function(){var obj = db.test.findOne(); emit(obj._id, 1);}, reduce: function(key, vals){ return Array.sum(vals); }, out: "mrout" })
```

But note this is not ideal performance wise and also will not work if you introduce sharding for either collection.

The preferred approach is to add the deviceId into message documents.

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB you can't do that.

I suggest that you embed `deviceId` into message documents. Then you'll be able to group by this field.